# Swift - Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: swift

i'm trying to make a action in other storyboard but i'm getting this error

```
2019-12-24 07:44:32.861248-0800 test[1588:142069] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003631e50 UIView:0x7fc09d715410.width == - 16   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003631e50 UIView:0x7fc09d715410.width == - 16   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in 
<UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

i'm new in ios development, i know that other request are posted in stack overflow but i'm don't understand how to revolve my problem.

i create un Alert.storyboard with nothing

AlertViewController.swift with :

```
import UIKit

class AlertViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    a()
}

func a() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Something", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let opt1 = UIAlertAction( title: "Action 1", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("dskhgohg")
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    alert.addAction(opt1)
    present( alert, animated: true, completion: nil )
}
}
```

AlertService.swift

```
import UIKit

class AlertService {
func alert() -> AlertViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Alert", bundle: .main)
    let alertVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AlertVC") as! AlertViewController
    return alertVC
}
}
```

and i added a button in Main.storyboard with action in viewController

```
let alertService = AlertService()

@IBAction func btn() {
    let alertVC = alertService.alert()
    present(alertVC, animated: true)
    print("dsgjodig")
}
```

maybe i shoud not **action sheet** in **viewDidAppear**

Comment: The message is clear: `(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.` Please show what your constraints are.

Comment: @koen They don't have any constraints to show, it's a bug in the built-in constraints for action sheets.

Comment: yes, i don't have any constaints, it's just a new project with the above code and some properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All action sheets do that. It’s an Apple bug. It has no effect on your app’s functionality.  Ignore it and move on.